# Unity Google Cardboard build fails: "No resource found that matches the given name"

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr

Unity 5.6.0b9, gvr 1.2

Building for Android fails with :

```
AndroidManifest.xml:18: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/VrActivityTheme').
```

I *believe* that this issue may have appeared after I moved from gvr 1.1.0 to 1.2, but I did the upgrade as per instructions.

In any case, how can I diagnose this issue?

ETA:
The offending line comes from the AndroidManifest.xml aggregated during the build and found in the staging area:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:isGame="false" android:theme="@style/VrActivityTheme">
```

The issue seems to be the tag

> android:theme="@style/VrActivityTheme"

This does not appear in the AndroidManifest.xml that I curated for the build and so am wondering how to discover who added it and why is it problematic.

I appreciate the advice to not use beta but we are trying to take advantage of the native Cardboard support in 5.6.  If I can learn conclusively that the Unity beta is the issue then I can resolve it in some otehr way.

Comment: Unity handles the creation of AndroidManifest.xml during an Android build and it looks like you're using a beta version of Unity so you should probably be on a stable version.  Regardless, you can always look at that file and see what's on line 18; the more info you can provide, the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original Poster here: I was reluctant to move away from the Unity 5.6 beta, but certainly moving Unity 5.5.2 has resolved our issues, perhaps it will for others as well.